# Is there any easy or automatic way to specify text color selector for click event?

Tags: android

I specified a selector drawable for the background of a layout as below, so when user clicks on the layout, the layout will have a different background. But, I didn't specify color selector for the TextViews in the layout, because there are many TextViews with different colors and I am too lazy to define color selector for them. So the text color keeps the same when the layout is clicked. My questions is, is there an automatic way to specify that the text color is highlighted/changed when the layout is clicked, so I don't have to define color selector for each of the TextViews in a layout? Thanks.

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
    >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="@color/my_green"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="@color/my_blue"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/text1"

        />
      </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define a theme as an XML file and set it with `Activity.setTheme()` - that will globally apply to everything.